# Alamofire Invalid value around character 0 in laravel

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, alamofire

I use alamofire to send post data to server but it cannot send to my server I use laravel to get user data
this my code

`viewController`

```
Alamofire.request("mysite/api/user",method:.post,parameters:["uids":uids],encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)

                break
            case .failure(let error):

                print(error)
            }

}
```

and in php server

```
public function seeUser(Request $request) {

    $uid = $request->input('uids');
    //...... and get to model table to query
return response()->json([
      'status' => 'user'
]);
}
```

and log response error is

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: Listen to response.error and see what it says.

Comment: response is `responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))`

Comment: Okay.  And what does a search engine tell you about it?

Answer (score 1):

It does mean that you JSON is not correct.

Try to response as a String and check it

```
Alamofire.request("mysite/api/user",method:.post,parameters:["uids":uids],encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                print(response)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
}
```

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo have you tried response as String (.responseString)?

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo What your server response for (.responseString)? When you response as a String Alamafire doesn't Serialize data and you will print plain string and chek it for correctness.

Comment: server response a HTML code of my homepage if use responseString

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo It could be not correct request (endpoint, parameters and etc.) or server side problem. Try to test your API with Postman why it's HTML instead JSON.

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo try to change encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody And let me know if helps.

Comment: I try to encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody it same Invalid value around character 0

Answer (score 0):

It clearly indicates that web service has problem. API not responding valid JSON.
Hit API in Postman and see Response in both JSON and HTML format

Answer (score 0):

The server is not able to give a valid JSON object in response. To get what your server is responding, you can either use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) or some other networking tools. Using Alamofire, you can also get the entire string, which is being responded by the server, with following lines of code:

```
Alamofire.request("mysite/api/user",method:.post,parameters:["uids":uids],encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { response in
    print("Response String: \(response)")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @YasuhiroKondo If responseString is giving you an HTML string, then please hit this API from Postman and Preview the error. There must be some issues with the back-end logic while returning the response.